# How to hide a VBScript in a Word

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, batch-file, vbscript

How can I hide a .vbs file in a document (Word, excel, etc.)? It should also be executed when I open the document.

I tried it with the command 'copy' but it didn't execute the script.

Comment: Doubt you can do it with a VB Script - Google **VBA Macro** - it's fairly easy to convert VBS to VBA code. FYI this kind of question is better suited for [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052612/run-macros-once-word-doc-is-opened)

Answer (score 1):

A Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) Macro can execute automatically when
the document is opened, but there is no way to hide it.

This is especially true because a Word documents that contains macros
must be in the `.docm` format and not `.docx`,
which is already a big giveaway hint.
Another hint is that when the document is downloaded from the internet
and opened, Word will ask (once) permission to execute macros,
which is an even bigger giveaway hint.

For more information about VBA, see Microsoft
[Get started with Visual Basic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/getting-started/).